# Func and sealed issue

Tags: c#

I have to use a library which has many classes in it of different shapes. I have to use them to do various functionalities.

For example, I have a `class Circle` which exposes only one method `double Calculate(Func )'. I read about Func, Action, delegates but somehow I am not completely sure. I tried:

```
var circle = new Circle(10);
circle.Calculate(radius * 2 * 3.14);
```

But it doesn't work.
Then I tried to create a new class `MyCircle` and inherit the Circle to implement some functionalities but I got an error:

> 'MyCircle' cannot inherit from sealed class 'Circle'

What should I do?

Comment: It would be `circle.Calculate(radius => radius * 2 * 3.14);`

Comment: seems like an odd class. Why not circle.Circumference as a caclulated proerty or simply `circum = circle.Radius * 2 * PI`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably the class is defined something like this:

```
public sealed class Circle 
{
    private double radius;

    public Circle(double r)
    {
        radius = r;
    }

    public double Calculate(Func<double, double> operation) 
    {   
        return operation(radius);
    }
}
```

Since it is [sealed](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/sealed) you cannot inherit from it.
Also, the radius is a private field of the object, so you do not have access to it.
This means you need to use the `Calculate` method by providing a `Func` to it. In case you don't know what a [Func](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb549151(v=vs.110).aspx) is, it is a predefined delegate. Something like a function pointer in C but type safe.

This is how you calculate the circumference:

```
var circle = new Circle(10);
circle.Calculate(r => 2 * Math.PI * r);
```

You can go ahead and calculate the area ;)

Answer (score 1):

`Func<double,double>` means a function that takes a double and returns a double

so you want a lambda that looks like  `circle.Calculate(radius => radius * 2.0 * 3.14)`

or you could have a Method

```
double Circumference(double radius)
{
   return radius * 2.0 * 3.14
}
```

and then

```
circle.Calculate(Circumference)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
double Calculate(Func<double, double>)
```

According to this signature, the function expects a `Func<double, double>`. That is a function which takes a single parameter of type `double` and returns a `double`. So something like the following:

```
double GetCircleCircumference(double radius)
{
    return radius * 3.14 * 2;
}
```

You could then pass that method to the function:

```
circle.Calculate(GetCircleCircumference);
```

You could also pass in a *lambda function* which saves you from defining that  method first:

```
circle.Calculate(radius => radius * 3.14 * 2);
```

Of course, whether this will produce any useful result depends on what `Calculate` is actually doing. Maybe the documentation will help you (I personally think that “Calculate” is a terrible name for a method—calculate what?!).

As for the error message you get, *“'MyCircle' cannot inherit from sealed class 'Circle'”*, this means that `Circle` was created as a sealed class, like so:

```
public sealed class Circle
{
    // …
}
```

This means that the author of that class had the indention of “sealing it off” for inheritance. So you cannot inherit from it; you deliberately cannot make a subclass of it. If you wanted to expand the behavior, you would have to use a different way of doing that, for example using composition.